# C# initialize object in get accessor

Tags: object, properties, initialization

Until now I would create a property called "Names" us such:

```
class Class1
{
    private string[] names;

    public string[] Names
    {
        get
        {
            return names;
        }

        set
        {
            names = value;
        }
    }

    Class1()
    {
        names = new string[] { "Peter", "John" };
    }
}
```

But lately I have seen some code doing this:

```
class Class1
{
    private string[] names;

    public string[] Names
    {
        get
        {
            // Initialize object here
            if (names == null)
                names = new string[] { "Peter", "John" };

            return names;
        }

        set
        {
            names = value;
        }
    }

    Class1()
    {
        // No initialization here
    }
}
```

So what these guys did was to only create an instance when it is needed. Seems like pretty good programming practice to me, saves on memory and cycles. Also helps in keeping the constructor tidy.
I have tried to get some more information and stumbled across Lazy Initialization which seems to do almost the same thing. My question is, is this good programming practice? Are there some pitfalls that I am not seeing or could I happily adapt this practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one issue that the constructor is synchronized while the getter is not. so in a multithreaded case the get can init more than one instance.

Comment: mmm... interesting, don't understand it yet but it is exactly these kind of things that I wanted to know. So it would just be better to stick with the first convention if I would like my classes to support being used in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: You should always do if cause you can never know how the code will change in future and who is going to use it. The constructor purpose is to initialize the object state. So just let him serve this purpose